# Web Services - GET Request Article (HAL+JSON)

Tags: services, 8

I'm trying to make a **GET request** to a specific article on my drupal 8 website (local). These are the steps I've done:

1. Enabled all 4 Web Services modules at the modules page
2. Created an article (url: http://dp8studyxb14copy.dev/node/4)
3. Changed permissions for **Access GET on Content resource** for all users (also Anonymous Users)
   [image]
4. Installed [REST UI module](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui).
5. Changed settings for content nodes (admin/config/services/rest/resource/entity%3Anode/edit)
   [image]

   6. Make a GET request
      [image]

But the problem is as you can see is that he returns HTML... . Now when I make a REST export view with a list of articles it works ... But not from a node itself.. .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 doesn't use accept headers for this anymore because it was problematic for caching.
Use *?_format=hal_json* instead.